# Embed git commit ID in the .so

Tags: linux, meson-build

In Windows, I can impress or update information including a build version into a DLL after it is built, as a post-process step before deploying.

There does not seem to be such a feature in Linux shared object files.
It appears that I need to include this while building.

How can I have meson automatically put the git commit ID of the current repository state into a text file so I can refer to that in the source code?  In the end, I want the .so file to "know" its own version and will (for example) log that as part of its operation, or can return that string from a published API of that library.

I understand that meson has "generative" features, but I could not follow how to use it from the online manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[vcs_tag](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#vcs_tag)** command:

```
git_version_h = vcs_tag(command : ['git', 'describe', '--tags'],
            input : 'git_version.h.in',
            output :'git_version.h')
```

> This command detects revision control commit information at build time
> and places it in the specified output file. This file is guaranteed to
> be up to date on every build.

You should provide *git-version.h.in* in your code base with **@VCS_TAG@** which will be replace with git commit id (result of the command), replacement string can be changed - see docs.

The file will be placed in the configured build directory in the same relative directory, so that *output* can be used as it's replacing the *input* in-place, e.g. you can include *git_version.h* from the directory where *git_version.h.in* is located.

And note, that

> you must add the return value to the sources of that build target. Without that, Meson will not know the order in which to build the targets

e.g.

```
executable('myprog',
       'myprog.c',
       git_version_h
       )
```

**UPDATE**
Here is working sample project:

```
$ cd vcs_sample
$ find        
.
./dir
./dir/meson.build
./dir/git_version.h.in
./meson.build
./main.c

$ cat meson.build 
project('vcs_sample', 'c')
subdir('dir')
executable('myvcs', vcs_dep, 'main.c')

$ cat main.c     
#include "stdio.h"
#include "dir/git_version.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv [])
{
    printf("git version = " MY_GIT_VERSION "\n");
    return 0;
}

$ cat dir/meson.build 
vcs_dep=vcs_tag(input:'git_version.h.in',
        output:'git_version.h',
        replace_string:'@GIT_VERSION@')

$ cat dir/git_version.h.in
#define MY_GIT_VERSION "@GIT_VERSION@"
```

Building/running

```
$ meson build/
$ ninja -C build/
$ ./build/myvcs
git version = R0.1.1+
```

And if we look inside generated ninja file, we can notice this works because **dir** *is* added to compiler include paths:

```
build myvcs@exe/main.c.o: c_COMPILER ../main.c || dir/git_version.h
 DEPFILE = myvcs@exe/main.c.o.d
 ARGS = -Imyvcs@exe -I. -I.. -Idir -fdiagnostics-color=always <...>
```

Comment: The `git-version.txt` file appears in the output directory.  How does the source file know the path in order to `#include` it?

Comment: it will be placed in the same relative directory where input file is located. e.g. if you place it in src/generated and configured build directory as build/ so it will be placed in build/src/generated so in source files it can be assumed it's located src/generated, you can include the git-version.txt (or better call git_version.h in this case)  directly from directory where git_version.h.in is located

Comment: I can't `#include "git_version.h"` because the `build.debug/` (or whichever) is not found on the `#include` path.  It does not "just find it" there.  I don't follow "include it directly from the directory where git_version.h.in is located" ... it is not in the same directory as the *.in file, and there is nothing to make it look in the output directory.

Comment: @JDługosz I've updated with minimum working project which shows what I mean "include it directly ..."

Comment: hmm, having a `subdir` with its own `meson.build` file seems to be the key.  So why doesn't that use output directories like the main `meson.build`?

Comment: yes, I cannot use dir/git_version.h.in in vcs_tag(..) due to meson.build:4:0: ERROR:  Output 'dir/git_version.h' must not contain a path segment, but sudbir doesn't play role - I could place git_version.h.in in root dir and in main.c #include "git_version.h" the similar way - the subdir was just for example (to better show what I meant before).

Comment: > I could place git_version.h.in in root dir and in main.c #include "git_version.h"
Sorry, that's simply not the behavior I'm seeing:  the output file appears in the build directory (for whichever build configuration I'm running), _not_ the same directory as the input file, as indicated in my earlier comment.

Comment: it _will_ be placed in build directory, but why do you need its exact location - I don't understand. It can be included to any source file anyway - meson will take care. I didn't say "it will be placed in the same directory as the input file" - I said it can be included as if it's located in the same directory as the input file.

Comment: How does meson take care of it?  The build directory was not added to the include search path and the `#include` fails at compile time.  It did not work for me, thus my initial comment.

Comment: if you check build/build.ninja you'll see that directory _is_ included. I suspect you have build configuration problem. Have you tried to build from scratch? (removing build directory and then setup it again), or at least reconfigure, e.g. $ meson --reconfigure build.debug   ..... $ ninja -C build.debug ...... or how do you configure and build?

Comment: Updated with piece from build.ninja

Comment: I configured with `meson build.debug`.  I've looked inside the ninja file, and there is no `-I` options added pointing to the build directory: only those things I added with the `include_directories :` parameters.

Comment: I expect that the solution is that when I added the `vcs_tag` to the project, the automatic _regenerate_ did not figure out that it needed to add this path, while `--reconfigure` (or other configuration change) did pick it up.